# displaying last record in the database asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display the last record of a reference of the model Client:

```
 public class Client
{
    public int ClientID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]
    public string portfolio
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 public int AlterID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
   public virtual Alter Alter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I try to create a partial view first and so I create a partialModel.
But I am wondering if the property of this model is an Object Client:

```
 public partial class PartialModel
{
    public Client Client
    {
        get;
        set;
    }   
}
```

Could you tell me if it is the right method with the partial_view and how can I retrieve then the last record of Client.

Here is the way I retrieve and show a reference of Client:

```
  @model IEnumerable<Gestion_restrictions.Models.Client>

  @foreach (var item in Model) {
   <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.portfolio)
    </td>
     <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alter.Alter_name)
    </td>
   }
```

But how can I do this in the create view of Client and displaying only the last record.

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.portfolio)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.portfolio)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.portfolio)
    </div>
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlterID, "Alter")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("AlterID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlterID)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the purpose of your PartialModel class. Wouldn't you just like to show all the properties of the Client? Also, where's the class that holds a reference to the client?

Comment: The purpose of the partialModel is to create the partial view I followed this tuto [link] (http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html). And yes I just like to show all the properties of the Client of the last record but in the create view of Client, that when the user fill the form. For the class that holds a ref to the client I don't understand well what you mean. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a partial model for this.
In the case above, you model and the partial model is the same, just that it's one more level deep.

Here's the basic idea of what you need:

1. Create you partial view that will accept a model of *Client*.
2. Write your database code, or wather code that will fetch your clients from the server to return only the last record.

I can't provide you with sample code for this as you don't show us how you retrieve the data.
But if you have a list then you could do: List.Last();

1. Pass the item retrieved in point 2 to your partial view.

When you're in MVC views, something along those lines should be possible:

```
@model List<Client>

<div>
    @Html.Partial("MyPartialView", model.Last())
</div>
```

Note, the code is untested but something like this should be working.
This should get you started anyway.

As an alternative you can use your viewbag.
So in your code behind you could do something like:

```
ViewBag.MyLastRecord = and here the latest record.
```

In your view, you can then use:

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialView", ViewBag.MyLastRecord)
```

Comment: Can you explain me, how can I do for the partial view to be able to accept a model of Client ? And then Do I have to create a controller to write my database code ? can you explain more in details please thank you

Comment: Sure  can, but as explained yesterday, update your question with all the code that you have. Controller, View, Partial View, Model, ... (and don't cut the important parts).